# Clarify the usage of GenerateMessages() method

Tags: c#, botframework

Using the Prompter method to send custom cards in the FormFlow. Looking at the code saw that there is a GenerateMessages() method, which is always returning false for the below code. Can someone clarify why / when to use this method?

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d7/d6d/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_form_flow_1_1_advanced_1_1_extensions.html#abff216af1ae24937c78767e621477935

```
 .Prompter(async (context, prompt, state, field) => {
            var preamble = context.MakeMessage();
            var promptMessage = context.MakeMessage();

            if (prompt.GenerateMessages(preamble, promptMessage))
            {
                await context.PostAsync(preamble);
            }
            else
            {
                promptMessage.Text = prompt.Prompt;
        var attachment = Helper.GetAttachment();                    
                promptMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                await context.PostAsync(promptMessage);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for .GenerateMessages can be found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/497252e8d9949be20baa2cebaa6ce56de04461cf/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/FormFlow/IPrompt.cs#L248

It appears that false will be returned unless there are:

1. buttons or an image in the description AND
2. one or more Environment.NewLine characters in the Prompt

I haven't personally used it, but it seems this method would be useful when defining a multi-line prompt message using FormFlow. Since markdown is not supported in all channels, this method provides somewhat of a workaround: enabling multi-line messages.